# How to filter users that had an event between two other events in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table that looks like the following:

| user_id | event | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | launch | 2023-09-15 14:31:44 |
| 1 | buy | 2023-09-15 14:31:49 |
| 1 | cancel | 2023-09-15 14:31:50 |
| 1 | add | 2023-09-15 14:31:52 |
| 2 | add | 2023-09-16 14:31:40 |
| 2 | cancel | 2023-09-16 14:31:44 |
| 2 | launch | 2023-09-16 14:31:49 |
| 2 | buy | 2023-09-16 14:31:50 |
| 2 | buy | 2023-09-16 14:31:52 |
| 3 | buy | 2023-09-17 14:31:44 |
| 3 | cancel | 2023-09-17 14:31:49 |
| 3 | remove | 2023-09-17 14:31:50 |
| 3 | add | 2023-09-17 14:31:52 |

How do I filter users that had an event 'cancel' after event 'buy' and before event 'add' (with no regard to whether there were any other events between them or not)?

In other words, I need to get the following list of users:

1, 3

Thank you in advance

I tried to add columns 'buy_timestamp' and 'add_timestamp' and filter df like
df[df.event == 'cancel'].query('timestamp > 'buy_timestamp' & timestamp < 'add_timestamp')

But I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

If timestamps for the same user are sorted chronologically like sample dataframe, you can use the following code:

```
cond1 = df['event'].eq('buy').groupby(df['user_id']).cummax()
cond2 = df['event'].eq('add').groupby(df['user_id']).cummax()
out = df.loc[df['event'].where(cond1 & ~cond2).eq('cancel'), 'user_id'].unique()
```

out

```
array([1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'event': ['launch', 'buy', 'cancel', 'add', 'add', 'cancel', 'launch', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'cancel', 'remove', 'add'], 'timestamp': ['2023-09-15 14:31:44', '2023-09-15 14:31:49', '2023-09-15 14:31:50', '2023-09-15 14:31:52', '2023-09-16 14:31:40', '2023-09-16 14:31:44', '2023-09-16 14:31:49', '2023-09-16 14:31:50', '2023-09-16 14:31:52', '2023-09-17 14:31:44', '2023-09-17 14:31:49', '2023-09-17 14:31:50', '2023-09-17 14:31:52']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: It works for my sample, but in case when a user has 'add' after 'buy' , but event 'cancel' before 'buy', it will be included in the output, won't it? And I need only the cases, when 'cancel' took place between these two events.

Comment: @clssyyy123 I misunderstand of your question a little. I have updated my answer accordingly. However, the approach to context and unfolding remains the same.